Kotlin - Filter by generic type parameter of an abstract generified class
I have a generified abstract base class with the bounded type param T: Shape and a collection of type T
abstract class ShapeContainer<T: Shape>(val shapeConsumer: Consumer) {
    val shapes : List<T>

    init {
        shapes = shapeConsumer.consume().filterIsInstance<T>()
    }

}

class SquareContainer(consumer) : ShapeContainer<Square>(consumer) {
    // use the shapes list here which contains only Squares
    val squares : List<Square> = shapes
}

I wish to use the type parameter T to filter out instances of type T. However what i get is
Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead
There are MANY questions on this error but not something that addresses this specific problem. How can we do this?

Does this answer your question? How does the reified keyword in Kotlin work?

@Leviathan only partially. since the other problem was getting the actual KClass to work with the filterIsInstance method. There were multiple ways of using it such as using filterIsInstance or shapeClass.javaClass which didnt work

Apparently at runtime, in kotlin, T does not contain any type information to do the filtering. So we need to add an additional parameter in the constructor shapeClass to hold the type information and use that while filtering
abstract class ShapeContainer<T: Shape>(val shapeConsumer: Consumer, private val shapeClass: KClass<T>) {
    val shapes : List<T>

    init {
        shapes = shapeConsumer.consume().filterIsInstance(shapeClass.java)
    }

}

class SquareContainer(consumer) : ShapeContainer<Square>(consumer, Square::class) {
    // use the shapes list here which contains only Squares
}

val squareContainer = SquareContainer(consumer)
val squares: List<Square> = squareContainer.shapes

